# como convertir este formato de fecha Tue Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 1984 al formato 10/01/1984 en jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, date

tengo mi variable fechaNacimiento  de Tipo Date a la cual le paso una fecha que viene de un WS de tipo XMLGregorianCalendar

```
fechaNacimiento = DateUtils.convertXMLCalenarIntoDate(datosProbatorios.getDatosPersonales().getFxNacimiento());
```

pero al mostrarlo en pantalla sale de esta forma  Tue Jan 10 00:00:00 CST 1984 y quiero que sea de esta manera 10/01/1984, como le puedo hacer?

Comment: no, me equivoque, solo darle ese formato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa [`<f:convertDateTime>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertDateTime.html).
Puedes anidar esto en cualquier componente de entrada y salida. Las reglas de patrón son las mismas que [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.dateField}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: excelente, gracias!